# MongoDB Error ( ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.ye1nx.mongodb.net )

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting this error when I run my app.js file

```
Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.ye1nx.mongodb.net
```

I am trying to console the database list but it's giving this error

[image]

Comment: That is a DNS timeout while attempting to resolve the SRV record.  Perhaps try a different DNS service?

Comment: Try to connect different MongoDB cluster and yes, you have to whitelist your IP in cluster side

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exact same error. I managed to establish a connection with my cluster by simply changing the connect to cluster "version" to 2.2.12 in the connect window -> connect your application -> version. Of course you have to change the connection URL in your app to the new one that is going to give you.

[mongo-connect-version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZxST.png)